# Syntax error when updating

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm a bit of a noobie when it come to SQL, I'm using Access 2013 and I'm trying to update a date field in one table, using id numbers from a different table to only update specific ones.

The query I have is:

```
UPDATE Leadsavailable SET First_Usage_Date = '23/04/2014'
from leadsavailable r
inner join WorkingTable_GOSH g
    on g.[lead number] = r.[Lead number] 
where g.Type = 'GOSH'
```

but I keep getting errors and don't know why.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Well, I think you can not use FROM and INNER JOIN clauses in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "23/04/2014" from leadsavailable r inner join WorkingTable_GOSH g on g.[Lead Number]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sorry im in a mobile:

```
UPDATE Leadsavailable A
INNER JOIN WorkingTable_GOSH B
ON A.[lead number] = B.[Lead number]
Set A.[First_Usage_Date] = '23/04/2014'
Where B.Type = 'GOSH';
```

Comment: I had to change B.Type to A.Type but then this worked exactly as I needed it to. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming my understanding of your requirement is correct, and you want to update all records in `Leadsavailable` that have a matching record in `WorkingTable_GOSH` with `Type = 'GOSH'` then this will give you the results you're after:

```
UPDATE Leadsavailable 
SET First_Usage_Date = '23/04/2014'
WHERE [lead number] in (SELECT [Lead number] 
                        FROM WorkingTable_GOSH 
                        WHERE Type = 'GOSH')
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in your original query is having the table name listed twice.  It should look liek this:

```
UPDATE r
   SET First_Usage_Date = '23/04/2014'
  FROM leadsavailable r
inner join WorkingTable_GOSH g on g.[lead number] = r.[Lead number] 
where g.Type = 'GOSH'
```